# How can I properly link to a header that has a page break before it?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, bookmarks, hyperlink

This is pretty frustrating. I've inserted a table of contents and am trying to link those contents to their appropriate headers. The top level headers, when linked, are linking to the last line of text on the previous page. It looks something like this:

Page 1

```
Company Business Plan

(white space)
```

Page 2

```
Table of Contents

 1. Table of Contents
 2. Executive Summary
 3. General Company Description

(white space)
```

Page 3

```
Executive Summary

(white space)
```

So now, what happen's when I click the first TOC item, it will take me to page 1 where the white space is. When I click the second TOC item, it will take me where the white space  is on page 2. This continues  through my entire TOC. I don't know how to properly link or line-break the items. I don't want to have to create bookmarks after the titles, but if that's the only option I will.

Comment: Does it mke any difference if you implement the page break by specifying Page Break Before in the relevant paragraph style, or (if necessary) in the individual heading paragraphs?

Comment: Are you using the automatic table of contents? I was just testing the automatic table of contents 1 and when I ctrl+click the links the cursor will jump to the beginning of headers. You cursor is jumping to where exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your level 1 headings set up with the Heading 1 style?  If not, apply that style to each level 1 heading.  Next, format the TOC:

[image]

Select the number of levels you want and then click on "Options".

[image]

Check the "Styles" box and the heading styles you want to use for your TOC levels.  Scroll the entire list to make sure there aren't other styles that have a level assigned.  If you see one, delete it.  If you want to modify your TOC styles, click the "Modify" button, click on the TOC level and modify from there.

Answer (score 1):

1. What does (white space) consist of? It is probably better to remove such white spaces.
2. Try to use the option 'Page break before' in paragraph styles of your headers.
3. Also, check the paragraph style of this (white space). It could probably be the same style as a header, which can cause problems - TOC entries link to (white space) as to headers.

Comment: #2 sounds promising.